# Invalid Accountmanager auth token

Tags: android, webserver, accountmanager, auth-token

Hello I'm trying to validate the token I've created with the accountManager from my php server but I keep getting the error "invalid token" from google server on my php server... Here is the code :

```
private String updateToken(boolean invalidateToken, int accountref) {
    String authToken = "null";
    try {
        AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(TestAuthActivity.this);
        Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType("com.google");
        AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> accountManagerFuture;
        if(TestAuthActivity.this == null){//this is used when calling from an interval thread
            accountManagerFuture = am.getAuthToken(accounts[accountref], SCOPE, false, null, null);
        } else {
            accountManagerFuture = am.getAuthToken(accounts[accountref], SCOPE, null, TestAuthActivity.this, null, null);
        }
        Bundle authTokenBundle = accountManagerFuture.getResult();
        authToken = authTokenBundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN).toString();
        if(invalidateToken) {
            am.invalidateAuthToken("com.google", authToken);
            authToken = updateToken(false, accountref);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Dialog d = new Dialog(TestAuthActivity.this);
    d.setTitle("Token :" + authToken);
    d.show();

    createSession(TestAuthActivity.this, authToken);

    return authToken;
}
```

So I'm getting a token then I'm sending it to my php server :

```
<?php

if( isset($_POST['authToken'])){        

    //pour que la réponse s'affiche comme du texte brut
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');

    /*partie à modifier*/
    $name = 'www.google.com';//nom du site

    $data = $_POST['authToken'];

    $envoi  = "POST /m8/feeds/contacts/default/full HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $envoi .= "Host: ".$name."\r\n";
    $envoi .= "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth='".$data."'\r\n";
    $envoi .= "Connection: Close\r\n";
    $envoi .= "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $envoi .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n\r\n";
    $envoi .= $data."\r\n";

    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    if($socket < 0){
            die('FATAL ERROR: socket_create() : " '.socket_strerror($socket).' "');
    }

    if (socket_connect($socket,gethostbyname($name),80) < 0){
            die('FATAL ERROR: socket_connect()');
    }

    if(($int = socket_write($socket, $envoi, strlen($envoi))) === false){
            die('FATAL ERROR: socket_write() failed, '.$int.' characters written');
    }

    $reception = '';
    while($buff = socket_read($socket, 2000)){
       $reception.=$buff;
    }
    echo(json_encode($reception));

    socket_close($socket);  
}
?>
```

and I keep getting the error : 401 invalid token :S

Does anyone have a solution or a good sample (couldn't found one that matches what I want to do !)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two possible problems you might have:

1. **The auth token has expired.** When you call your method `updateToken()` to get the token you need to set the parameter `invalidateToken` to true to make sure you get a fresh token.
2. **The value of `SCOPE` is wrong.** Based on the code you've provided it looks like you are trying to use the Google Contacts API, for this API `SCOPE` should have the value **https://www.google.com/m8/feeds**